# Flask login (no database)

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm trying to implement the following views in flask:

1. /index

        * shows a form with username and password entries

        * upon submission, redirects to 2
2. /params

        * shows another form with more entries

        * is only viewable if they provided a username and password for 1

        * upon submission, redirects to 3
3. /upload

        * does magic() with the fields entered from 1 & 2

        * is only viewable if they filled in 1 & 2

---

**Every** tutorial I have seen assumes that you use a database. The username and password from 1 are **not** checked against any database. They are used for ntlm authentication only...

Can this be done? Or am I misusing flask?

Comment: I've implemented everything except for the @login_required functionality correctly. It seems like no matter what I do, it wont verify (so I can't view the pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a session to store the username and password and a flag specifying that the user has completed the first two steps:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'something'


def validate_upload(f):
  def wrapper():
    if 'completed' not in flask.session or not flask.session['completed']:
      return flask.redirect('/')
    return f()
  return wrapper

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def home():
  html = """
  <form action='/second' method = 'POST'>
    <input type='text' name='username'>
    <input type='password' name='password'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>
  """
  return html

@app.route('/second', methods=['POST'])
def second():
  username, password = flask.request.form['username'], flask.request.form['password']
  flask.session['username'] = username
  flask.session['password'] = password
  flask.session['completed'] = True
  return flask.redirect('/upload')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET'])
@validate_upload
def do_something():
  return '<p>Doing something with values</p>'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mention NTLM authentication, I assume you're running inside a Windows network. If that is the case, I'm not sure why you'd need a form where users can enter username and password.

NTLM and Kerberos use the principal of the Windows session to authenticate the user with services running inside the same domain. The user logs in once to Windows and that identity is auto-magically used to authenticate the user when calling services.

Flask supports this using the [Flask-Kerberos](https://flask-kerberos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module